# How to make width of view equal to superview in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I have `Button`

[image]

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("MyButton")
                    .color(.white)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 17))
            }
            .frame(height: 56)
            .background(Color.red, cornerRadius: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to pin it to supreview's edges (trailing to superview's trailing and leading). Like this:

[image]

`HStack` doesn't help me, and it's expecting.
Fixed `frame` or width equals `UIScree.size` are not flexible solutions.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to use `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier

Add the next code

```
        Button(action: tap) {
            Text("Button")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
```

Padding modifiers will allow you to have some space from the edge.

Keep in mind that the order of modifiers **is essential**. Because modifiers are functions that are **wrapping** the view below (they do not change properties of views)

Comment: `.infinity` is a nice thing, thank you! But it's imposible to set some instets to superview. But if set .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity) to `Text`, and add `padding()` to `Button` - it will work!

Comment: How can I add specific height for the button? Like if I have to set the button's height as 43px, how can I do that?

Comment: One small addition, is that now you can use the `.padding(.horizontal, 20)` if you want the padding on both sides, without mentioning left and right individually.

Comment: Why minWidth: 0 ? When I remove it I find my view larger than the parent view. I don't understand the logic here

Comment: .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32 , height: 48, alignment: .center) & dont use padding. This also works

Answer (score 31):

You can use `GeometryReader`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader

According to Apple:

> This view returns a flexible preferred size to its parent layout.

[image]

It is a flexible solution, as it changes according to the parent layout changes.

Comment: I can confirm that this works to set the button to file the entire width, however I can't seem to add padding to either size of the button.

Comment: Don't add code as picture

Comment: I edited to add some code example based on this solution

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pure SwiftUI solution where you want to fill the width of the parent but constrain the height to an arbitrary aspect ratio (say you want square images):

```
        Image("myImage")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .aspectRatio(16.0 / 9.0, contentMode: .fit)
```

Just replace 16.0 / 9.0 with whatever aspect ratio you want.

I spent about a day trying to figure this out because I didn't want to use GeometryReader or UIScreen.main.bounds (which isn't cross-platform)

Edit: Found an even simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

Simple adding following to your code will make the button extend edge to edge. (You can add padding as well if you want)

```
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
```

The entire Button code will look like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("MyButton")
                    .color(.white)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 17))
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 8)
            .padding(.bottom, 8)
            .background(Color.red, cornerRadius: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## iOS 17

From iOS 17, the correct way to do this is to use `.containerRelativeFrame` modifier because using `.infinity` width on the frame actually pushes the parent's frame to have an infinite width.

So it would be like:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("MyButton")
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) //  This should be inside the `label` parameter of the `button`. Otherwise it would be NOT touchable
        .padding(-10) //  This is here to make space to the edges. Yes it should have a NEGATIVE value
}
.frame(height: 56)
.background(.red)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution:

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("MyButton")
                    .color(.white)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 17))
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 56)
            .background(Color.red, cornerRadius: 0)
        }.padding(20)
}
```

But I'm not sure that it is the best.  May be someone will find more elegant solution/

Comment: One issue here is that the button is tappable outside of its visible bounds. What that means is that the user can incorrectly tap on a button, even if they were tapping on whitespace.